# Why has PHP Module Penetration on Apache been falling for the past 5 years?

Tags: php, apache

According to [Security Space](http://www.securityspace.com/s_survey/data/man.200908/apachemods.html?mod=UEhQ) The penetration of PHP on Apache servers has been falling since the start of 2005, my question is why? PHP seems to be doing very well, are people using Ruby or other languages.....

Comment: neat way to promote your site! good work! :-)

Comment: @danp: You think the poster owns Security Space?

Comment: was a slightly off the cuff remark.. I guess I should keep them to myself ;) that said, you do see quite a few 1 score people posting links in answers and nothing else. Maybe I have a suspicious mind..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More professional hosters are migrating to PHP on FastCGI and suexec. And this isn't counted into that graph (which presumably is about mod_php penetration, not PHP). It also wouldn't count Quercus or Project Zeros PHP runtime, nor HipHop.

Answer (score 1):

Did you scroll all the way to the bottom?

> Readers are cautioned that the Growth percentages are based on a module's market share penetration rather than the absolute number of modules we detected. Thus, it is possible for the number of modules to increase, while the growth is actually a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer, besides the normal caveats in this statistical data, is that with more maturity of suexec using fastcgi+suexec is terribly more secure & desirable on a multi-user hosting platform then php as a module, for which the `safe_mode` possibilities were a incomplete attempt to readd some security.